# PHP - parsing xml with possible multiple items not using simple xml

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have been parsing xml files using the following, but have now come into a situation where there could be multiple items instead of only one possible value.  I need to be able to save those to an array so I can run a foreach loop on them.  I do not want to use simplexml in this case so please do not recommend that - I want to keep the method the same as other places I do similar - this case just happens to possibly send multiple items.

Here is what I have always used in the past which works fine when there is only one name/value :

```
//receive the xml and trim
$xml_post = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//save posted xml to file to ensure correct post values
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../something/something.txt', print_r($xml_post, true));

//open domdocument
$xml = new DOMDocument();

//load xml
$xml->loadXML($xml_post);

//parse the XML into a usable array
$xmlval = array();

//these are all fine because there can only be one value sent
$xmlval['orderid'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("orderid")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xmlval['test'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("test")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xmlval['referrer'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("referrer")->item(0)->nodeValue;

//******these can be repeated so I need to figure out how to save these as an array in something like $xmlval['items'] so I can run a foreach loop - foreach($xmlval['items'] as $item) and access like $item['productname'] and so on for each group

$xmlval['productname'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("productname")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xmlval['quantity'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("quantity")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xmlval['returnprice'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("returnprice")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xmlval['originalprice'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName("originalprice")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Here is an example of what would be sent as stored in something.txt that I save when it comes in :

```
<return > 
    <orderid>ggfegse53534353</orderid> 
    <test>true</test> 
    <referrer>gfdgsdggfgrer</referrer> 
    <items> 
        <item> 
            <productname>something</productname> 
            <quantity>1</quantity> 
            <returnprice>$19.95</returnprice> 
            <originalprice>$19.95</originalprice> 
        </item>
        <item> 
            <productname>something2</productname> 
            <quantity>5</quantity> 
            <returnprice>$19.95</returnprice> 
            <originalprice>$19.95</originalprice> 
        </item>
        <item> 
            <productname>something3</productname> 
            <quantity>8</quantity> 
            <returnprice>$19.95</returnprice> 
            <originalprice>$19.95</originalprice> 
        </item>
    </items> 
</return>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want. It iterates through the list of `productname`, `quantity` etc. values, adding them to the `items` array in turn:

```
$xmlval['items'] = array();
$productname = $xml->getElementsByTagName("productname");
$quantity = $xml->getElementsByTagName("quantity");
$returnprice = $xml->getElementsByTagName("returnprice");
$originalprice = $xml->getElementsByTagName("originalprice");
for ($i = 0; $i < $productname->length; $i++) {
    $xmlval['items'][$i] = array('productname' => $productname->item($i)->nodeValue,
                                 'quantity' => $quantity->item($i)->nodeValue,
                                 'returnprice' => $returnprice->item($i)->nodeValue,
                                 'originalprice' => $originalprice->item($i)->nodeValue);
}
print_r($xmlval['items']);
```

Output:

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
    [productname] => something
    [quantity] => 1
    [returnprice] => $19.95
    [originalprice] => $19.95
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [productname] => something2
    [quantity] => 5
    [returnprice] => $19.95
    [originalprice] => $19.95
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [productname] => something3
    [quantity] => 8
    [returnprice] => $19.95
    [originalprice] => $19.95
  )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YdvC1)